# Should work both listview setOnItemClickListener and edittext editable in custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, onclicklistener

Issue: When i set `android:focusable="false"`, `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to list item `editTexview`, `editText` is not focusable, if i remove those 2 line code `listView` `setOnItemClickListener` won't work. My requirement is should work both.

My Custom List Item XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@drawable/comment_bg"
     android:orientation="vertical">

     <EditText
         android:id="@+id/list_item_post_edittext_add_comment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="@dimen/layout_margin_10"
         android:background="@drawable/comment_bg"
         android:drawableEnd="@mipmap/ic_send_dark_48"
         android:drawablePadding="@dimen/layout_margin_10"
         android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_send_dark_48"
         android:hint="Add a Comment..."
         android:inputType="text"
         android:padding="@dimen/layout_margin_10"
         android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
         android:textColorHint="@color/colorGray"
         android:textSize="12sp" />

</LinearLayout/>
```

Comment: What exactly is it, you want to happen when the user clicks the list item?

Comment: #Ridcully, its EditText inside custom listview, and i want to access edittext to comment and item click to move next activity

Comment: I got partial solution, in adapter getview set edittext ontouchlistener focusable true and in setOnEditorActionListener set focusable false

Comment: Try add: `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to LinearLayout of your custom list item. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Set onTouchlistener on view of individual item in adapter class. Also you have to manage the state of list such that when list is being scrolled, onTouch should be disabled and when not scrolled, onTouch should work as usual. It works fine on recycler view in my project. Should work with ListView as well.

```
itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                if(!isScrolling)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item clicked ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

and to manage isScrolling flag,

```
rv.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(newState == SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING)
            {
                isScrolling=true;
            }
            else
            {
                isScrolling=false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: #Zealous Sorry!, am using ListView

Comment: try the idea with listview please.